# Refer to same branch of previous alternate group

Tags: regex, matching, pcre, string-matching

I need to build a regex with capture groups that would result in the following:

```
12-34 # match: (1) (2) (3) (4)
1a-2b # match: (1) (a) (2) (b)
12-3b # nomatch
```

In a nutshell, if the first part has two digits, then the second part must also have two digits. And if it has  a letter, then the second part must also have a letter.

In PCRE flavor, `(\d)(\d|[abc])-(\d)(\d|[abc])` matches the third line, so it is too permissive.

Using named groups, `(\d)(?<named>\d|[abc])-(\d)(?P=named)` matches no line at all, for it requires the second characters to be exactly the same. It is too restrictive.

Is there a way I can require that my second alternate group `(\d|[abc])` takes the same branch as the first `(\d|[abc])`?
Or do I need to fall back on the full `(?:(\d)(\d)-(\d)(\d)|(\d)([abc])-(\d)([abc]))` which duplicates parts of my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PCRE you may use this regex:

```
^(?:(?<num>\d{2})-(?&num)|(?<alnum>\d\pL)-(?&alnum))$
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/KtKXIW/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<num>\d{2})`: named group `num` for matching 2 digits
- `(?<alnum>\d\pL)`: named group `alnum` for matching 1 digit followed by a letter
- `(?&num)`: Match same sub-pattern as in named group `num`
- `(?&alnum)`: Match same sub-pattern as in named group `alnum`

---

**Another option** is to use [conditional sub-patterns in PCRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) as:

```
^(?:(?<num>\d{2})|\d\pL)-(?(num)\d{2}|\d\pL)$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/KtKXIW/2)

Comment: Okay. Your first solution does not exactly mean "take the same branch", but it works alike and it avoids duplication. Thank you :)

Comment: It seems that the PCRE construct `(?&..)` has no equivalent in [python regexes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Too bad :\

Comment: If you can install `regex` module in python then complete PCRE feature set is available.